# Geonodes question: Is there a way to set different widths on one single curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I'm trying to get a different radius/width for my curves.
This is what I got so far, I'm generating a mesh from my curves where I can control the subdivision and the width.
The thing is I can't get different widths working on the curve. It's always one  set value along the whole curve. The only time I could vary the width is when I use the  'random value' node (see pic). My goal here is to make the width vary with a curve node (it's visually easier for me and also I'm bad at math :p)

Thanks for your help guys[image]

Comment: Did you try putting the *Resample Curve* before *Set Radius* ? I'm pretty sure after your *Set Radius*, each point has its own radius (indicated by the diamond-shape input, if it was one value for the whole curve, it would have been a circle).

Answer (score 1):

The [Set Curve Radius](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/write/set_curve_radius.html)-node can only set the radius on *points*. To get more control of the radius through out the spline you need to [resample](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/operations/resample_curve.html) it. Then you can use the [Spline Parameter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/read/spline_parameter.html)-node's *Factor* through a [Float Curve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math/float_curve.html)-node to make it whatever shape you want.

[image: Setting the curve radius of a curve using a spline parameter-node to a float curve-node and finally into a set curve radius node]

Comment: I don't think that's what he's looking for since there is already a _Set Curve Radius_ in the original nodetree in the question. And the text says "My goal here is to make the width vary with a curve node", so I guess he's rather looking for a _Float Curve_ node.

Comment: I think you are correct. I was hasty. I've updated the answer. Thanks for the comment!